# PrimeNG Controls are not showing Invalid

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

We are using PrimeNG autoComplete component in our app. we would show all valid  invalid with "red".
By default, Angular mark all input fields with ng-valid style class unless we have any validation which makes the control invalid. This seems to be standard in Angular. PrimeNg Control are not behaving the same.

[image]

Now if I select a value from location autocomplete dropdown thn delete it same for the phone type in a number then deleted , validations are no longer triggered 
[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-3"
                                           [ngClass]="{
                                         'has-error':(ersaForm.get('phone').touched || ersaForm.get('phone').dirty ) &&
                                         !ersaForm.get('phone').valid
                                         }">

                                        <label for="phoneId" class="control-label">Phone</label><br />
                                        <p-inputMask mask="(999) 999-9999" formControlName="phone" (onBlur)="checkValidity();" unmask="true"  styleClass="form-control" [style]="{'width': '100%','height':'34px'}"  id="phoneId"  placeholder="Phone (required)"></p-inputMask>

                                    </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-3"
                                     [ngClass]="{
                                     'has-error':(ersaForm.get('location').touched || ersaForm.get('location').dirty ) &&
                                     !ersaForm.get('location').valid
                                     }">
                                    <label for="locationId" class="control-label">Location</label>
                                    <p-autoComplete formControlName="location" id="locationId" (onBlur)="checkValidity()" [suggestions]="iOffice" forceSelection="true" placeholder="Office (required)" inputStyleClass="form-control" (completeMethod)="searchOffice($event)" [style]="{'width': '100%','display': 'inline-flex','height':'34px'}" field="ORG_BRH_ADDR_LN" dataKey="ORG_BRH_NO" [dropdown]="true"></p-autoComplete>

                                </div>
```

**TS Code**

```
this.ersaForm = this._fb.group({
            phone: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            location: ['', Validators.required],

            });

        checkValidity(): void {
                Object.keys(this.ersaForm.controls).forEach((key) => {
                    console.log('inside validation');
                    this.ersaForm.controls[key].markAsDirty;
                //    this.ersaForm.controls[key].
                });
            }
```

Comment: anyone can help!

Comment: anyone please ...this i driving me crazy

Comment: you will get a better response if you put a sample stackblitz project

Answer (score 1):

This is 2 years old now, but I hit this issue and worked out a solution. Hope it helps others out.

I'm using v.12 of PrimeNG.

For p-dropdowns at least, it appears that the border is changed to red when the element has both `ng-invalid` and `ng-dirty` classes applied to it. I needed the border to be red only when invalid. I added the following override, which solved the issue for me.

```
p-dropdown.ng-invalid > .p-dropdown {
    border-color: #f44336; // This color HEX value comes from PrimeNG.
}
```

Comment: You should consider using exported variables for PrimeNG theme colors, so you don't have to change this manually